# Return input to adjacent output label after loop to calculate values

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting the correct results but I would like to be specific with the calculated values displayed for each label that is adjacent to each input.

Currently using two line breaks & it seems to line up with inputs by luck.
[image]
Program calculates book cost based on the number of pages printed:

1 - 500 pages 2 cents per page

500 - 100 pages 1.5 cents per page

1000+ pages 1 cent per page

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPriceResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //VARIABLES
        double[] arrPrintPageNums = new double[3];
        double total = 0;


        //INPUTS
        arrPrintPageNums[0] = double.Parse(txtInputBook1.Text);
        arrPrintPageNums[1] = double.Parse(txtInputBook2.Text);
        arrPrintPageNums[2] = double.Parse(txtInputBook3.Text);


        //PROCESS (i = INDEX NUMBER(0 1 2 3 4))
        for (int i = 0; i < arrPrintPageNums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 0 && arrPrintPageNums[i] <= 500)
            {
                lblBook1Price.Text += "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 2) + "\n\n";
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.02;
            }
            else if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 500 && arrPrintPageNums[i] <= 1000)
            {
                lblBook1Price.Text += "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 1.5) + "\n\n";
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.015;
            }
            else if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 1000)
            {
                lblBook1Price.Text += "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 1) + "\n\n";
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.01;
            }
            else
            {
                lblBook1Price.Text += "ERROR! OUTSIDE PRINT RANGE" + "\n\n";
            }

        }


        //OUTPUT
        lblBookPriceTotal.Text = "Total price: " + total.ToString("C2");
    }
}
```

Desired result:

Book 1 Pages Input - Book 1 Total Print Cost Label

Book 2 Pages Input - Book 2 Total Print Cost Label

Book 3 Pages Input - Book 3 Total Print Cost Label

Button 'Book Print Cost' - Grand Total Print Cost Label

Comment: it seems that you have correct expected output and current output

Comment: @AkashKC I want to assign the calculated values to each label rather than using one label with two line breaks.

Comment: For adjusting your label text, you can adjust it with visually aligning with your adjacent label text. As simple trick, you can set adjacent label Y-axis point to your output label Y-axis point.

Comment: @AkashKC not really what I am asking.
Can the loop (or another loop) calculate output to each of the three labels?
Total seems fine/working.

Comment: Are you asking about label position or good way of calculating output value of each label ?

Comment: Just guessing... are looking to change the labels as the user types into the text box? If so you need to hook up the events for each text box.

Comment: @JohnG Your interactivity / update idea is solid. Any code examples  you can suggest? So each keystroke will be the event rather than button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of labels that match your labels to the right of the inputs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bookPriceLabels = new Label[] { lblBook1Price, lblBook2Price, lblBook3Price };
    }

    private Label[] bookPriceLabels;

    private void btnPriceResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //VARIABLES
        double[] arrPrintPageNums = new double[3];
        double total = 0;


        //INPUTS
        arrPrintPageNums[0] = double.Parse(txtInputBook1.Text);
        arrPrintPageNums[1] = double.Parse(txtInputBook2.Text);
        arrPrintPageNums[2] = double.Parse(txtInputBook3.Text);

        Label[] labels = new Label


        //PROCESS (i = INDEX NUMBER(0 1 2 3 4))
        for (int i = 0; i < arrPrintPageNums.Length; i++)
        {           
            if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 0 && arrPrintPageNums[i] <= 500)
            {
                bookPriceLabels[i].Text = "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 2);
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.02;
            }
            else if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 500 && arrPrintPageNums[i] <= 1000)
            {
                bookPriceLabels[i].Text = "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 1.5);
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.015;
            }
            else if (arrPrintPageNums[i] > 1000)
            {
                bookPriceLabels[i].Text = "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 1);
                total += arrPrintPageNums[i] * 0.01;
            }
            else
            {
                bookPriceLabels[i].Text = "ERROR! OUTSIDE PRINT RANGE" + "\n\n";
            }

        }


        //OUTPUT
        lblBookPriceTotal.Text = "Total price: " + total.ToString("C2");
    }
}
```

Comment: your coding magic has inspired my day!

I moved the one line (array initialization):

Label[] bookPriceLabels = new Label[] { lblBook1Price, lblBook2Price, lblBook3Price };

Inside the click button event.

Many thanks mate ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I was quite confused by the picture you supplied and the code that is posted. From the first picture it “Appears” you are using three (3) labels to the right of each text box. However the supplied code only uses one label i.e... `lblBook1Price`. This is confusing to use this label for book 1 for all the books. You are correct is certainly blind luck that they line up properly. Remove one of “\n”’s in the line: `lblBook1Price.Text += "Print Cost: " + (arrPrintPageNums[i] * 1) + "\n\n";` and it won’t line up properly.

Again this seems odd and not very intuitive to others who are reading your code. One solution would be to simply use 3 different labels as the first picture shows, one for each text box. At least you are not using the book 1 label to output the book 3 costs. I hope this makes sense.

The other problem I see is user sanitation, your code wil crash if the user types in letters and not numbers. I hooked up two events to handle this. KeyPressed event to allow only numeric input and the TextChanged event if the user copy and pastes invalid text. Hope this helps.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  updateForm();
}


private void updateForm() {
  double total = 0;
  //INPUTS
  double curCost = 0;
  curCost = GetBookCost(txtInputBook1, 0.02);
  lblBook1Price.Text = curCost.ToString("C2");
  total += curCost;

  curCost = GetBookCost(txtInputBook2, 0.015);
  lblBook2Price.Text = curCost.ToString("C2");
  total += curCost;

  curCost = GetBookCost(txtInputBook3, 0.01);
  lblBook3Price.Text = curCost.ToString("C2");
  total += curCost;

  //OUTPUT
  lblBookPriceTotal.Text = "Total price: " + total.ToString("C2");
}

private double GetBookCost(TextBox pagesText, double pricePerPage) {
  double totPages = 0;
  double.TryParse(pagesText.Text, out totPages);
  double cost = totPages * pricePerPage;
  return cost;
}



private void txtInputBook1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  KeyPressManager(sender, e);
}
private void txtInputBook2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  KeyPressManager(sender, e);
}
private void txtInputBook3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  KeyPressManager(sender, e);
}

private void KeyPressManager(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  char keyPressed = e.KeyChar;
  if ((!char.IsDigit(keyPressed)) && (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))) {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}

private void txtInputBook1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextChangedManager(sender, e);
}
private void txtInputBook2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextChangedManager(sender, e);
}

private void txtInputBook3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextChangedManager(sender, e);
}

private void TextChangedManager(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
  int userInput = 0;
  if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out userInput)) {
    updateForm();
  } else {
    if (tb.Text != "") {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for number of pages!");
      txtInputBook1.Text = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am currently learning to code / create very basic program with C#. Hence the ambiguous label arrangement (sorry to cause confusion). Non intentional but it worked in the interim.
Your supplied code opens up many other possibilities. I really like the real time cost update through the textbox input. Will create another project to try your rework of the code.
The validation also looks very interesting. Thanks again.

Comment: the validation seems to partially work & the program runs (gives some result) even if the user types in letters ($0.00). I thought the output would update on each KeyPress? That would be cool.

Comment: Users can type letters but the text box will not display them. The labels DO update with each key press in the textboxes. Not sure if I follow your last comment.

Comment: I went through it again & copy / pasted your code. Rechecked names etc etc. Working OK for for me on button click but not on KeyPress event. Could I possibly be missing something else in the top of the Form1.cs file? Thanks again.

Comment: I can only assume the key press events are not wired up properly. Once they are properly implemented, you will see the button is unnecessary as the totals update with each key pressed. Make sure the `KeyPress` events are set in the designer or in your code.